# Strip U+10000-U+10FFFF from javascript strings

Tags: javascript, unicode

Tried `string.replace(/\u10000-\u10FFFF/g, '')`, but sadly `\u` doesn't support 10000+

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To specify code points beyond U+FFFF, you need to look for [UTF-16 surrogate pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Code_points_U.2B10000_to_U.2B10FFFF):

```
string.replace(/[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]/g, '')
```

---

For future reference: One of the current ECMAScript [proposals](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3aproposals) is to add a `/u` flag to support [Unicode supplementary characters](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3aunicode_supplementary_characters), which would allow:

```
string.replace(/[\u{10000}-\u{10ffff}]/gu, '')
```

Comment: Confirmed this works by testing with 호텔 and an emoji. 호텔 remained as expected and emoji was removed as expected. I suspected surrogate pairs, but was trying `\uD800\uDC00-\uDBFF\uDFFF`. Thanks so much!

Comment: For others looking, this surrogate pair calculator will help: http://www.russellcottrell.com/greek/utilities/SurrogatePairCalculator.htm