# Detect non valid XML characters (javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex

Yesterday I made a question about [Detect non valid XML characters in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29009868/detect-non-valid-xml-characters), and this expression works as expected:

```
String xml10pattern = "[^"
                + "\u0009\r\n" // #x9 | #xA | #xD 
                + "\u0020-\uD7FF" // [#x20-#xD7FF]
                + "\uE000-\uFFFD" // [#xE000-#xFFFD] 
                + "\ud800\udc00-\udbff\udfff" // [#x10000-#x10FFFF]
                + "]";
```

However, I realized it would be better checking for invalid characters on client side using javascript, but I didn't succeed.

I almost achieved, except for range U+10000–U+10FFFF: http://jsfiddle.net/mymxyjaf/15/

For last range, I tried

```
 var rg = /[^\u0009\r\n\u0020-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFD\ud800\udc00-\udbff\udfff]/g;
```

but it doesn't work. In [regextester](http://www.regextester.com/), tells "Range values reversed". I think it is because `\ud800\udc00-\udbff\udfff` is intepreted as 3 expressions:

```
\ud800; \udc00-\udbff; \udfff
```

and, of course, the middle one fails.

So, my question is how *convert* above java regular expression into javascript.

Thanks.

**==== UPDATE ====**

Thanks to @collapsar comments, I tried to make two regular expressions. 
Because of that, I realized I can't negate characters `[^...]`.  
It'll discard correct characters like `U+10001`. I mean, this is **not right**:

```
function validateIllegalChars(str) {
    var re1 = /[^\u0009\u000A\u000D\u0020-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFD]/g; 
    var re2 = /[^[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]]/g;
    var str2 = str.replace(re1, '').replace(re2, ''); // First replace would remove all valid characters [#x10000-#x10FFFF]
    alert('str2:' + str2);
    if (str2 != str) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Then, I tried next (http://jsfiddle.net/mymxyjaf/18/):

```
function valPos(str) { 
    var re1 = /[\u0009\u000A\u000D\u0020-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFD]/g; 
    var re2 = /[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]/g;

    var str2 = str.replace(re1, '').replace(re2, ''); 
    if (str2.length === 0) return true; 
    alert('str2:' + str2 + '; length: ' + str2.length);
    return false; 
}
```

However, when I call this function: `valPos('eo' + String.fromCharCode(65537))`, where `65537 is U+10001` it returns `false`. 
What is wrong or how can I solve it?

Comment: the `\u` notation (so far) only supports up to 32 bit codepoints. [This SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16346705) will solve your problem ( specify the code points in question as surrogate pairs ). However, you _should_ be able to use the original solution if you create a RegExp object from a  string: `new RegExp ( xml10pattern );` with `xml10pattern` defined as in your question.

Comment: @collapsar, I think it does not work. For instance, `U+D801` shouldn't be accepted (it's not valid XML) and it seems accepted: http://jsfiddle.net/mymxyjaf/16/. What is it wrong?

Comment: In your fiddle,you have nested character classes in your first regex. This is a syntax error. Follow the recipe in the cited answer - you cannot build  a single negated character class (ora single regex) because the limits of the offending code points will be represented by _2_ characters.

Comment: @collapsar, the expression I just used is `var re = /[^\u0009\u000A\u000D\u0020-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFD[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]]/g;`. It looks like it don't take `U+D801` as surrogate pair. It seems it only check first part `[\uD800-\uDBFF]`

Comment: @collapsar, so you mean I must use two regular expressions? One for 32-bits codepoints, and the other for `U+10000 - U+10FFFF`?

Comment: At least that's the way I understood the cited answer.

Comment: @collapsar Thanks, but still not working. Negate `(^)` won't work because it remove valid chars (like `U+10001`). So, I tried without negate: http://jsfiddle.net/mymxyjaf/18/ (function `valPos()`) , but I doesn't work, either.

Comment: Reverse your substitutions: `var str2 = str.replace(re2, '').replace(re1, '');` (instead of `var str2 = str.replace(re1, '').replace(re2, '');`)

Comment: I already did and nothing. I think something is wrong with regexp or with function `String.fromCharCode(65537)`, because I even tried simple sample like:  `var strA = 'eo' + String.fromCharCode(65537); var strB = strA.replace(/[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]/g, '');` and doesn't replace such character. I can't understand and I don't what else to try. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: Have you tested  different browsers? Perhaps it's just  a bug in the interpreter of a specific browser / version?

Comment: @MarvinEmilBrach, I tested on different version and OS of firefox, but not in other browsers. Not even this simple example works: http://jsfiddle.net/xpg9kvzp/. Should remove _weird_ character, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally solved.

The answer to my own question, as @collapsar told me, could be:

```
function validateIllegalChars(str) { 

    var re1 = /[\u0009\u000A\u000D\u0020-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFD]/g;  // #x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] 
    var re2 = /[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]/g; // [#x10000-#x10FFFF]

    var res = str.replace(re1, '').replace(re2, ''); // Should remove any valid character

    if (!!res && res.length > 0) {  // any remaining characters, means input str is not valid 
        return false; 
    }

    return true; 
}
```

The previous examples (the ones I post in jsfiddle) didn't work to me, because `String.fromCharCode(65537)` does no generate character with code point `U+10001`, as I thought, but `U+0001`.

Thanks for help.